# Detect changes on all input fields in form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I am using Reactive forms.It has lot of fields(input,select, etc) with save and print button.Here i have a scenario which is whenever the user changes any of the fields value the print button should be disabled.Initially the print button is in enabled state.I dont know how to handle the whole form inputs.Can anyone help me to sort this.

```
<div class="tab-content">
 <form [formGroup]="EditForm">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="title" class="control-label">
       <span>TITLE</span>                      
     </label>
     <div>
       <input type="text" size="27" formControlName="Title" pInputText>
     </div>
  </div>    

   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="title" class="control-label">
       <span>Department</span>                      
     </label>
     <div>
       <input type="text" size="27" formControlName="Department" pInputText>
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The below is component.ts

```
 constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
   ){
    this.EditForm= this.formBuilder.group({
        Title: ['', Validators.required],
        Department: ['']
    });
```

Comment: Changes?? And when will it be enabled? can listen to `this.editForm.valueChanges`

Comment: Changes means editing the input value.Initially the button is in enabled state.When the user edits the form the print button should be disabled .

Comment: Yeah, I understood that much... see the answer below, you can get all the form data under the valueChanges subscription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the below code:

dirty:- true if some control was modified

```
    <button  type="submit" [disabled]="EditForm.dirty" (click)="exportPdf()">
        <span >PRINT PAGE</span>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the below code in the constructor. Whenever there is change in value in any control of the **EditForm**, below code will execute.

```
this.EditForm.valueChanges.subscribe(
    (selectedValue) => {

      // Disable the print button here
      // Console.log(selectedValue);

    }
);
```

**valueChanges** is a property of AbstractControl that emits an event every time when the value of control changes which is available for FormControl, FormArray and FormGroup.

it returns Observable of any type.

Comment: where will i call this function?I mean inside the ngOnChanges?

Comment: You can add it in either constructor or ngOnInit

Comment: I want to call this function whenever the form fields value gets changed.ngOnInit is called after Angular has initialized all data-bound properties of a directive

Comment: By adding this in ngOnInit or constructor, what you do is, it will register the subscription first. whenever the values change in the form, this registered subscription will be executed.

Comment: that's wonderful but how you can know if the event was fired from on pageLoad of if the user interacted with the form element?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1) Declare a property in your component like this, basically it will be subscription to the form value changes

> private valueChangeSub: Subscription;

2) Update your ngOnInit to include the lines from below ngOnInit:

```
   public ngOnint() {
           this.valueChangeSub = this.EditForm.valueChanges.subscribe(
              (values) => {
                   // Code to disable the button
            });
    }
```

And then in your ngOnDestroy method you must unsubscribe:

```
public ngOnDestry() {
   this.valueChangeSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

We should never forget to unsubscribe any subscriptions.